# I keep getting : Reverse for 'delete_entry' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['deleteentry/(?P<input_id>[^/]+)/\\Z']

Tags: python, django

I am a begginer and tried to look up solutions from other threads to no avail,

**Here is my views.py** :

```
@login_required(login_url='/login')
def delete_entry(request, input_id):
    input=Diary.objects.get(pk=input_id)
    input.delete()                    
                   
    
    return redirect('home')
```

**Here is my urls.py** :

```
urlpatterns = [
        path('', views.welcome, name='welcome'),
        path('home', views.home, name='home'),
        path('MyEntries/', views.MyEntries, name='entries'),
        path('deleteentry/<input_id>/', views.delete_entry, name='delete_entry'),
       
    ]
```

**Here is my html code** :

```
<p>Hello, {{user.username}} !</p>

{%   for article in articles   %}
<p> {{ article.title}}<br>
    {{ article.description }} <br>
    {{ article.date        }}
    <div class="card-footer text-muted">


</p>
<a href="{% url 'delete_entry' input.id   %}" class="delete">Delete</a>
</div>
{% endfor %}

{%  endblock  %}
```

Comment: Shouldn't this be `"{% url 'delete_entry' article.id %}"`?

Comment: `{% url 'delete_entry' input.id   %}` What is `input`?

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, this is because `input.id` resolves to the empty string, so likely `input` does not exists, or it has no `id`.

Likely you should work with `article.id`, or perhaps even more robust, use `article.pk`. If you delete items, you need to make a DELETE or POST request, so you can *not* work with a link, you use a mini-form, so:

```
<form action="post" method="{% url 'delete_entry' article.pk %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" class="delete">Delete</button>
</form>
```

The view can be further improved by using [`get_object_or_404`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404), and restrict the view to only POST and DELETE requests:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.views.decorators.http import require_http_methods

@login_required(login_url='/login')
@require_http_methods(["DELETE", "POST"])
def delete_entry(request, input_id):
    input = get_object_or_404(Diary, pk=input_id)
    input.delete()
    return redirect('home')
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the precise answer, However, I Have the error : NOT FOUND the requested resource was not found on this server, after setting DEBUG = False and allowed host ['*']